# How to create an image overlay in C#

Tags: c#, windows, image, overlay

I'm trying to create an application that'll run in the background of applications, but
have occasional popups (For control switching and stuff in a gesture camera program).
How would I make an image overlay a focused window, and keep that window in focus?

Comment: There's no mechanism in Windows to push a window into the user's face.  Any program that tries to work around this is universally despised.  Use a NotifyIcon, tell the user you've got something interesting to tell him with the ShowBalloonTip() method.

Comment: What I was thinking about doing is just having a window that is only 20% visible stay full screened in a way, and pop on top of whatever there is with the message then loose focus after a gesture or something. The ShowBalloonTip() may work as well though.

Comment: You can add the WS_EX_TRANSPARENT style to your window by overriding CreateParams().  This will prevent your app from receiving focus and will allow clicks to "pass through" it....